# How to use apply method to get another column from another dataframe in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

i want to ask about apply method in pandas dataframe from my two's dataframe

Dataframe A:

```
request_id type  request_date  entity_id   

    1      OCR    2023-06-01   20220401003
    2     Match   2023-01-01   20220401004
```

and DataFrame B:

```
     entity_id    status       notes
0  20220401001  rejected       rejected
1  20220401002    cancel       cancel
2  20220401003  approved       approved
3  20220401004  approved       approved
4  20220401005   pending       waiting
```

from two dataframe above, i want to use apply method using entity_id as parameter to get status and notes column from dataframe B into dataframe A. the result i expected is:

```
request_id type  request_date  entity_id       status     notes

    1      OCR    2023-06-01   20220401003     approved   approved
    2     Match   2023-01-01   20220401004     approved   approved
```

Comment: won't works because the entity_id was varchar data type

Comment: are the datatypes different in both dataframes ? If yes change them to string and merge it. It will work. Use below code.
`dfA.entity_id = dfA.entity_id.astype(str)
dfB.entity_id = dfB.entity_id.astype(str)
output_df = dfA.merge(dfB, on='entity_id')`